# Weird encoding problem, with 00 added

Tags: c#, character-encoding, biztalk

For some reason, as in picture shown below, my system always adds `00` after each char in the ASCII text file. I can only find this problem when using the binary format view of the text file (e.g. in UltraEdit). If I just open it using Notepad, everything is ok. But this is a huge problem since if I send this file to another system for processing, they complain it is not a valid file due to all of the `00`:

[image]

Is it because of some system setting?

Comment: How do you write the file ? It seems you are using a multibyte encoding such as UTF-16. You should agree with the other system on the encoding to use. (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 8):

That's not an ASCII file. It's a UTF-16 file (at a guess; it seems very likely) - which is what Notepad is detecting, basically.

Either:

- Change how you're producing the file to *actually* use ASCII (or potentially UTF-8)
- Tell the receiving system to read it as UTF-16

Comment: thanks, I am not writing the file, I am reading the file from file system, write the content to the sql server and read it back. what I find is my file on the file system is ok. It got problem of the double zeros (00) when in the database, and it got the same problem when reading out of the database.

Comment: @adamgump: But *something* has created the file. It didn't just magically get there. So either you need to change whatever's producing the file, or change how you're reading it. You can read it by explicitly passing in `Encoding.Unicode` of course.

Comment: @adamgump: Are you writing into a char field in the SQL server or a blob?

Comment: @adamgump: No, ignore SQL - you should either fix what's writing the file, or what's reading the file. Currently those two bits aren't using the same encoding. What you do with the data later is somehwat irrelevant - you need to make sure you're reading it correctly to start with.

Comment: I am using BizTalk WCF SQL to call a store procedure with the varcharmax as the paremter. I dumped the SQL request prior to its leave with BizTalk, open it, everything is ok. Now I go check my SQL, I can see the 00 is added.

Comment: @adamgump: as in you retrieved the file from the server? What tool/code did you use to retrieve the file shown in your image, as that is your likely culprit.

Comment: This is resolved. This is the workflow, the file is moved to a biztalk receive location, biztalk calls a store procedure, the store procedure updates the service broker queue as varchar(max). For some reason, the service broker seems to store the data in a weird encoding, thus resulting when biztalk poll it again using UTF-8 getting error. I fixed it by calling Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgContent)); which the msgContent is the value from the database

Comment: @adamgump: That's a really bad idea - you may very well lose data in some situations. If you've read a string in the wrong encoding to start with, you can't just use that sort of code to "convert" it. You should read it in the right encoding to start with.

Comment: There is a pipeline component for fixing encoding: http://winterdom.com/2006/01/fixmessageencodingcustompipelinecomponentsample